# Use Textures Panel Textures in Shader Editor

Tags: texturing, materials, particles, shaders

I have a texture created in the textures panel to dictate the density of a particle system. I want to use it in the shader editor as well.

Is there a node that will access the texture?

Do I have to save the texture (and how can I do that)?

Comment: Object level textures can't be used in shaders and vice versa, unless you bake them to an image texture

Comment: How would I bake them?